# A congruence equation

Tags: number-theory

[image]

I  don't  have any clue . Can  chinese  remainder  theorem  can  be  used?  I am  studying  number  theory  but I am not  an  expert  as  you  can  see. This  question  was  set  in  the exam  and  I could  not  answer.

Comment: Do you know Euler's Theorem?

Comment: Hint: $a^{12}\equiv 1\pmod 13$

Comment: Chinese remainder is clearly not usable, $13$ is prime. Do you even know what CRT says?

Answer (score 1):

$a^{24}=(a^{12})^2\equiv 1^2\equiv 1 \bmod 13$ by Euler since $\varphi (13)=1$ as $13$ is prime.

From here you want $1\equiv 6a+2\iff 6a\equiv12\iff 66a\equiv132 \iff a\equiv 2 \bmod 13$.

Out of the primes listed only $41$ and $67$ satisfy this.

Comment: no. We  need  6a+2(congruent to) 1(mod 13) not  6a-2

Comment: Thanks, thankfully I had a double mistake, so everything else is fine.

Comment: Two mistakes by  chance  landed  at  the  correct  answer.  Not  fine  at  all.  And the  step 66a(congruent to)132(mod 13)  is  totally  redundant.

Comment: how is it redundant? It's telling you the multiplicative inverse of $6\bmod 13$ is $11$. This is an important step.

Comment: It  is  redundant  because 6a(congruent to) 12 (mod 13)  directly  implies  that  a(congruent to)2 (mod 13). as  13  is a prime . We did not  need  the  inversion  here.

Comment: I don't see how it is immediate, where does $2$ come from?

Comment: ok.  6a(congruent to) 12 (mod 13)   is  equivalent  to  saying  13 divides (6a-12)=6(a-2) . Now 13  being a  prime and not  dividing 6 , must  divide  a-2 . Thus a(congruent to)2(mod 13). That's a  theorem about the primes.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense.